# Prove $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left ( 1 + x^{2^n} \right ) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$

Tags: summation, generating-functions

I was just messing around trying to learn generating functions and a friend sent me this question.

Prove:
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left ( 1 + x^{2^n} \right ) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
$$

I'm not entirely sure how to begin so I'd love it if you someone could hint me to the right direction (not answers for now).

Comment: Multiply LHS by 1-x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1. Any integer number has a unique binary representation.

Hint 2. You may also try to prove by induction that for $N\geq 1$,
$$\prod_{n=0}^{N-1}\left ( 1 + x^{2^n} \right )=
\sum_{k=0}^{2^{N}-1} x^k.$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Note that $$\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(1+x^{2^{k}}\right)=\prod_{k=0}^{N}\frac{\left(1-x^{2^{k+1}}\right)}{1-x^{2^{k}}}=\frac{1-x^{2^{N+1}}}{1-x}.
 $$

Comment: Wow!! I didn't know this telescoping proof. Thank you!! =)

Comment: @mathbeing You're welcome.